# How will while loop work in sql server user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I use a while loop inside my user defined function and the function returns a variable at last.. will the function return value for each iteration or will it return for only one iteration and end

If I consider a scenario as below

```
create or replace myFunction(
-- I declare some variables (input and locals)
@variable1 varchar(4000)
)
as
returns varchar(4000);

while loop begins

  do some calculations on variable1(for eg)

increment counter for while
end while loop

return @variable1;
end
```

In this case will return work for every while condition or only once.. What can be done to return for every while true condition

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As mentioned in your prior question, why are you using a `WHILE` at all. Multi-line Scalar Function can be (very) slow, and `WHILE` loops *are* slow. If you want to write a function, use an inline table value function.

Comment: @Larnu I am migrating objects from Oracle to SQL Server.. There in oracle FOR LOOPs were used.. I see while loops can be used as for loops in sql server

Comment: Loops *can* be used, yes, that doesn't mean they *should* be. Just like you can use a Hammer to put a screw in the wall.

Comment: My question is.. will the function return multiple times if I use while condition and given that it is true.. or not.. I will try implementing it using inline table value function as you suggested.. I am completely new to sql server..

Comment: SQL (and thus T-SQL) is a set based language and so you should be using set based solutions. A `WHILE` is the complete opposite of that methodology. What you should *really* be asking is how to convert your looping Oracle function to a inline TVF in SQL Server.

Comment: *"will the function return multiple times"* A **scalar** function returns a **scalar** value.

Comment: @Larnu Oh Okay! It seems I need to redevelop the logic then.. I was expecting if there was any direct alternative.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to answer your question - a scalar UDF will return a single value. YOU must write the code to return that value based on the functionality you wish to implement. The UDF will not and cannot return multiple values nor can you return a single value multiple times using a loop of any sort within the function. You have a lot to re-learn - best to get started sooner.

Comment: Sounds like you might want an inline Table Valued Function instead (of the form `RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN SELECT ...` with a single `SELECT` statement)